# Process gets terminated after a while that was started through a web service

Tags: wcf, iis

I have this exe that is started through my web service. Weird thing is it gets terminated automatically after a while the memory gets a bit higher (highest 60MB it isn't even that high). If I run the exe from a command line it runs fine and doesn't crash. It is also specific to a machine, it works fine on other machines! I feel like I'm missing some sort of settings and I can't figure out which one.

This is what my iis pool settings look like:

[image: app pool settings]

UPDATE:

Total memory consumption doesn't get that high. But the cpu usage is over 85% as soon as the process starts.

Comment: IdleTimeout is set to terminate? also if server memory gets to 90% or 95%, app pools are automatically killed unless specified otherwise

Comment: @mahlatse where can I specify not to kill it?

Comment: Try setting IdleTimout to 0.